# my items is not the same as the id name

Tags: php

I was doing a tutorial of shopping cart.
However,
the result I get back is not the same as the id.
meaning,
when I want to display the name for the items,
although the id is different, but the name and the price that I gotten back is all the same.
why is it so?

Here is my coding.

```
 <?php require_once('Connections/MyDatabase.php'); ?>
<?php
//initialize the session
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

// ** Logout the current user. **
$logoutAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?doLogout=true";
if ((isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) && ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] != "")){
  $logoutAction .="&". htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_GET['doLogout'])) &&($_GET['doLogout']=="true")){
  //to fully log out a visitor we need to clear the session varialbles
  $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = NULL;
  $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = NULL;
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = NULL;
  unset($_SESSION['MM_Username']);
  unset($_SESSION['MM_UserGroup']);
  unset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']);

  $logoutGoTo = "login.php";
  if ($logoutGoTo) {
    header("Location: $logoutGoTo");
    exit;
  }
}
?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

mysql_select_db($database_MyDatabase, $MyDatabase);
$query_supermarketDetails = "SELECT * FROM supermarket";
$supermarketDetails = mysql_query($query_supermarketDetails, $MyDatabase) or die(mysql_error());
$row_supermarketDetails = mysql_fetch_assoc($supermarketDetails);
$totalRows_supermarketDetails = mysql_num_rows($supermarketDetails);
?>
<?php require_once('Connections/MyDatabase.php'); ?>
<?php
//script error reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','1');
?>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['pid'])) {
    $pid = $_POST['pid'];
    $wasFound = false;
    $i = 0;
    // If the cart session variable is not set or cart array is empty
    if (!isset($_SESSION["supermarketcart"]) || count($_SESSION["supermarketcart"]) < 1) { 
        // RUN IF THE CART IS EMPTY OR NOT SET
        $_SESSION["supermarketcart"][] = array(1 => array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => 1));

    } else {
        // RUN IF THE CART HAS AT LEAST ONE ITEM IN IT
        foreach ($_SESSION["supermarketcart"] as $each_item) { 
              $i++;
              while (list($key, $value) = each($each_item)) {
                  if ($key == "item_id" && $value == $pid) {
                      // That item is in cart already so let's adjust its quantity using array_splice()
                      array_splice($_SESSION["supermarketcart"], $i-1, 1, array(array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => $each_item['quantity'] + 1)));
                      $wasFound = true;
                  } // close if condition
              } // close while loop
           } // close foreach loop
           if ($wasFound == false) {
               array_push($_SESSION["supermarketcart"], array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => 1));
           }
    }
    header("location: cart.php"); 
    exit();
}
?>
<?php
//if user choose to empty cart
if(isset($_GET['cmd']) && $_GET['cmd'] == "emptycart")
{
    unset($_SESSION["supermarketcart"]);
}
?>

<?php
//render the cart for user to view
$cartOutput = "";
if(!isset($_SESSION["supermarketcart"]) || count($_SESSION["supermarketcart"]) < 1 ){
    $cartOutput .= "<h2 align = 'center'> Your shopping cart is empty</h2>";
}
else
{
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($_SESSION["supermarketcart"] as $each_item)
    {

        $i++;

    $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];

        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM supermarket WHERE id = '$item_id' LIMIT 1");
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $product_des = $row['description'];
    $price = $row['price'];

    $cartOutput .= "<h2>Cart Item $i</h2>";
    $cartOutput .= "Item ID: " . $each_item['item_id']."<br>";
    $cartOutput .= "Item Quatity: " . $each_item['quantity']."<br>";
    $cartOutput .= "Item Name: " . $product_des."<br>";

    $cartOutput .= "Item Price: " . $price."<br>";


}
}
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because into this line:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
```

you have a code "following"

```
$product_des = $row_supermarketDetails['description'];
$price = $row_supermarketDetails['price'];
```

that will not take the data from your db select query. It's taken from another place. Fixing this will solve your trouble, something like:

```
$product_des = $row['description'];
$price = $row['price'];
```

Edit: After reading some of your code i see that you have other problems, i will post it later if necessary some other code to fix the view of the right data.

To make the system dynamic you need to put some loop "idea" into it:

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $product_des = $row['description'];
    $price = $row['price'];

    $cartOutput .= "<h2>Cart Item $i</h2>";
    $cartOutput .= "Item ID: " . $each_item['id']."<br>";
    $cartOutput .= "Item Quatity: " . $each_item['quantity']."<br>";
    $cartOutput .= "Item Name: " . $product_des."<br>";

    $cartOutput .= "Item Price: " . $price."<br>";


}
}
```

The $cartOutput need to be put inside the loop to see everything right, as far as i see, it can be unnecessary...

Comment: my id doesn't show, and i've a lot of problems now. 
Items isn't in my cart

Comment: @user3156220 at the beginning of your code there is a session_start()? I do not see it anywhere.

Comment: there is.. it is together with the login

Comment: @user3156220 in the code you posted isn't there. You need to have it before all of your code into ALL of your page. Did you do a session var_dump to see if the session has the data?

Comment: Hi , i just did some admenment to my code. It is now stated that 
: Undefined index: item_id && when I add into cart, first item added is not shown, when I add again, then it will shown

Comment: this is wrong -> if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
} you need to start the session (with session start) BEFORE checking it.